# is it okay to wrap an <li> tag in an <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I currently have html code that wraps my **li** tags in my **a** tags like so:

```
<ul>
    <a href='#'><li>Home</li></a>
    <a href='#><li>Gallery</li></a>
</ul>
```

It works perfectly, but Is this semantically correct? is there any negative implication of writing my html like this?

Comment: Parent of li should be `UL` not anchor. Instead put anchor inside li tag.

Comment: I would rather add anchor tag around the text in your li

Comment: used to this <ul><li><a href="#"></a></li></ul>

Comment: There are many things which "work" , but should not be done. Think of traversing the DOM etc.
Stick to <ul><li><a>
You should not nest block elements into inline elements. <li> is a block element by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `href='#` should be `href='#'`